# How to allow CUPs to wake up printer once when in standby?

Tags: printing, raspberry-pi, cups

I an bringing up my home print server using RaspberryPi+CUPs

MY printer is HP Laserjet MTF m1212nf.

Apprently, I I was able to setup everything good enough to be able sending jobs over the network and get them printed.

However, one problem i am running into is that once I leave the printer Idle for some time, it seems to go into kinda standby mode (kinda power-saving mode) and then jobs i send show as completed in the CUPs interface, but they never get to be printed on paper.
From this point, the way to resume printing is to shut off and then on the printer and then things work again until next go into power saving mode.

Answer (score 0):

What you look for is Tea4Cups, which is a bridge beetween commands and cups.

For installation on RPi see here: (step 1-3) https://github.com/Felixel42/Printer-Pi-DCP-115C#tea4cups

Prefix your printer line i.e. *smb://yourprinter* so that it looks like that

```
 tea4cups:/smb://yourprinter
```

The configuration file is at */etc/cups/tea4cups.conf*

A minimal example is

```
[global]
directory : /var/spool/cups/ #you might need to adjust this
prehook_0 : wakeonlan yourmac #or whatever command you want to execute
```